# How to release beta version in maven

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-release-plugin

HI,

I was wondering how the general best-practice method for the following scenario is:

We have codefreeze in our company. So for that we like to release a release candidate for our maven projects. After testing this candidate shall be released.

So how can I create a "release" in maven so that it is handeled like a snapshot ? Maven should download always a newer/patched version of the RC version. 
Only after the testing and final release to a full version it should not...

So how can I make a release of a RC ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to make a release which is handled as a snapshot, because it's released. The best practice is to give the artifact an appropriate version. For example 1.0.0-RC1 and after fixing some problems 1.0.0-RC2 and finally 1.0.0...

Comment: Are you sure that 1.0.0 > 1.0.0-RC2?? i find conflicting answers but it seems to me that in maven 2 it was true but in maven 3 it is no true (i.e. RC2 is newer than the one without qualifier, which doesn't make sense)

Comment: See https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#version-order-specification

1.0.0-RC1 < 1.0.0-RC2 < 1.0.0